# VBA (Excel) Can't loop through range

Tags: vba, excel

The issue I'm currently facing is the fact that my code does not loop through the defined range, it stays stuck at the first line.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Vergelijk_prijs_en_staffel_click()

Dim xlRange As Range
Dim xlRange2 As Range
Dim xlCell As Range
Dim xlCell2 As Range
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim xlSheet2 As Worksheet
Dim ValueToFind
Dim lastRow As Integer

Set xlSheet2 = Sheets(1)
Set xlRange2 = xlSheet2.Range("I6:I5715")

For Each xlCell2 In xlRange2

If ActiveCell.Row > 5715 Then Exit Sub

ValueToFind = xlCell2.Value

    If xlCell2.Value = ValueToFind Then

        If Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DK" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("W" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DL" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("X" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DM" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("Y" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DN" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("Z" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DO" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AA" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DP" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AB" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DQ" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AC" & ActiveCell.Row).Value Then
            If Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DR" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AD" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DS" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AE" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DT" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AF" & ActiveCell.Row).Value Then
                If Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DU" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AG" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DV" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AH" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DW" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AI" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DX" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AJ" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DY" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AK" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("DZ" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AL" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("EA" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AM" & ActiveCell.Row).Value Then
                    If Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("EB" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AN" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("EC" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AO" & ActiveCell.Row).Value And Sheets("Tab 1 - Prijslijst").Range("ED" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Sheets("Tab 2 - Nieuwe prijzen").Range("AP" & ActiveCell.Row).Value Then
                        Sheets("Tab 3 - Prijslijst aangepast").Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                        xlCell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                    Else
                        Call ntofourty(xlCell2)
                    End If
                Else
                    Call ntofourty(xlCell2)
                End If
            Else
                Call ntofourty(xlCell2)
            End If
        Else
            Call ntofourty(xlCell2)
        End If

    Else

    xlCell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    End If

'Set xlSheet = Sheets(1)
'Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("I6:I5715")

If ValueToFind = "" Then
    xlCell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    Exit Sub
End If

Next xlCell2

End Sub
```

You see, the line at the end  `Next xlCell2` should make it so it goes to the next cell in the range and goes through the range and colors that cell. But right now, what the code does, is coloring the same cell over and over again.

I would really appreciate any help given!

Comment: Stop using ActiveCell !!!! There are dozens of answers on SO that will will explain why. And BTW it would have avoided your current issue.

Comment: Hi @PatrickHonorez, thanks for your answer. I'm quite much a newbie at Excel VBA. Could you perhaps point me in the right direction to avoid using ActiveCell?

Comment: @MauricevanDorst, in addition to what Harassed Dad has already mentioned about your code, I believe the main culprit here is your massive If statements with all the ANDs, plus you keep referencing the ActiveCells.Row, which I'm pretty sure you could change to xlCell2.row... If you were to tell us what your code is actually supposed to do, with some examples, then we could help you clean up your code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are colouring  rColour (which is always the first row)  when you want to colour xlCell2 (which is the cell that loops)

EDIT:

So looking at more detail I'm confused with this bit, and I think you are as well :-)

```
 For Each xlCell2 In xlRange2  'what this does is SET the variable xlcell2 
'to each cell in the range xlrange2

If ActiveCell.Row > 5715 Then Exit Sub 'this isn't needed because you defined the range 
to stop at row 5715 - it cannot exceed this.

ValueToFind = xlCell2.Value 'ok, so each time through valuetofind = 
'the value in the current cell pointed to by xlcell2

    If xlCell2.Value = ValueToFind Then 'so this is always true because valuetofind 
'changes at every row -so why have it?
And then you have a bunch of if statements that look at the activecell - 
'but we have no idea what that is - the activecell could be any cell - it could even 
'be on a different spreadsheet! Did you mean the row that contains the cell that xlcell2 
'is pointing to?
```

Comment: Hi @Harassed Dad, thanks for your answer. I tried applying xlCell2 instead of rColour where needed. I've edited the post to the updated version of my code right now but I've still got the same issue.

Also, you said rColour is always the first row. Could you enlighten me with the answer of why it is always the first row?